# ReOrder plugin in WordPress memory error

Tags: wordpress

The ReOrder plugin in WordPress gives me this error. How can I resolve this?

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 1048576 bytes) in
>   /home1/homegood/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1971

Answer (score 0):

This is a memory allocation error cause by the plugin asking the operating system for memory when none is available.

Options:

1. Physically, or virtually, add more memory to the server running your Wordpress installation.
2. Reduce the amount of memory other processes on the machine are using. Typically if you are running apache this is set up to eat any available memory to provide additional capacity - for most blogs or small websites this can be cut dramatically.
3. email the plugin developer or visit the faq page for the plugin
4. provide a few more details on what your server side set-up is and provide an output of memory usage to stack overflow and I can refine my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem. Insert this code at the end into post-types-order.php

$r['hierarchical'] = 0;

$args = array(

'sort_column' => 'menu_order',

'post_type' => $post_type,

'posts_per_page' => -1,

'orderby' => 'menu_order',

'order' => 'ASC',

'posts_per_page' => 100 // mymodif for 100 first post
);